# Extract Data widget flex viewer 2.5

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer, widget

I am working on the data extract widget for the flex 2.5 viewer. It has installed properly and works fine but the output is not what I expected. The tool will not divide or split polygons. For example when I draw the AOI the return will omit any polygons that have been split or divided. I was expecting to get all data in the AOI. Is this the way the tool works? Or is there something I can do to fix this? My .xml file for the widget is below:

-

--> 
- 
http://s2-cor-pangaea:8399/arcgis/rest/services/demo1/GPServer/Extract%20Data%20Task 
draw

Answer (score 1):

you will need to do an intersect between the featureRecordset you are using to make the selection, and the data you are selecting.

see: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000